# How to change data range of a chart with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro that would change the data source column of a chart.

The data range is C4:F13, 10 rows and 4 columns. The columns are variables and rows are samples. Sampling times are in column B, in a range B4:B13. I want to plot the variables as function of sampling time, and I have written a macro which takes the values from column C and plots them as a function of time(column B).

I want to have a macro that deletes current series from the plot and changes the data source to the next column. So every time that I would run the macro, it would to the same thing. Another macro for going back to the old values would be nice as well.
I’ve been trying to solve this but can’t figure out how to do it. At the moment my code looks like below. So I would like to change the value of the number with question marks around it by one and delete the old series, when I run the macro.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
'Variables
Dim Cht As ChartObject
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim Var As Range
Dim Dat As Range
Dim InputData As Variant

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set Sht = Worksheets("Trends")
Set Cht = Sht.ChartObjects.Add(100, 100, 500, 250)
Set Var = Sht.Range(Cells(4, ?3?), Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, ?3?).End(xlUp))
Set Dat = Sht.Range(Cells(4, 2), Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
Set InputData = Union(Var, Dat)

With Cht.Chart
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkersStacked
    .ChartStyle = 332
    .Legend.Delete
    .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
    .ApplyDataLabels
    .SetSourceData InputData
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Dat 
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .Name = Var.Cells(1).Offset(-1, 0).Value
            .Format.Line.Weight = 0.5
            .MarkerSize = 2
        End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using a variable, say `x`, in place of the 3 and then toyed with adding and subtracting numbers to it?

Comment: Are you set on using VBA? You can usually accomplish this kind of thing without VBA fairly easily My go-to charting resource ifor dynamic charts is Jon Peltier's website www.peltiertech.com. Jon has a lot of tutorials on how to do this kind of thing using slicers and/or functions.

Comment: Thanks jeffreyweir. I realized I don't need VBA, but OFFSET and COUNTA functions are enough.